# func init --docker-only creates a Dockerfile that uses .NET 6 docker image, but the project is .NET 8

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, vscode-extensions, azure-functions-core-tools

The Dockerfile generated by func init --docker-only uses other .NET version.

`func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated` creates functions project with .NET 8, then `func init --docker-only` creates Dockerfile that use .NET 6 images:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

When I do `func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated --docker` the generated Dockerfile uses .NET 8 images.

My Azure Functions Tools version is 4.0.5530.

I expected that `func init --docker-only` creates Dockerfile using .NET 8 images.

Answer (score 0):

> `func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated` creates functions project with .NET 8, then `func init --docker-only` creates Dockerfile that use .NET 6 images.

Because `func init --docker-only` commands creates a `in-process` image by default, `func init --worker-runtime dotnet-isolated` creates `.NET 8` image as only `isolated process` supports for `.NET 8` .

For reference check this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/ga-azure-functions-supports-net-8-in-the-isolated-worker-model/).

And in `in-process` , `.NET 6` is the only version which supports `in-process` model.

[link](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet) for `inprocess` Images.
[link](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated) for `inprocess` Images.

I created a http trigger function.

[image]

##### My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]